# Installing Webkit with apt

Tags: apt, webkit

Does Ubuntu include a way to install the Webkit development files (headers and libraries) using `apt`? Yes, you can install all sorts of Webkit *ports*, like Webkit-GTK or WebkitQT, but what about just installing plain Webkit development files (WebCore and JavaScriptCore)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebKit does not exist on Linux without it being a "port." There is no version of WebKit which doesn't require some toolkit, and thus has integrated API with that toolkit. You'll need to choose which toolkit package you wish to use, and install the appropriate -dev package for that version of WebKit. Also you can't develop for a single API and have it work with all version of WebKit.